# Listen to changes of all databases in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have a scenario where there are multiple (~1000 - 5000) databases being created dynamically in CouchDB, similar to the "one database per user" strategy. Whenever a user creates a document in any DB, I need to hit an existing API and update that document. This need not be synchronous. A short delay is acceptable. I have thought of two ways to solve this:

1. #### Continuously listen to the changes feed of the `_global_changes` database.

   - Get the db name which was updated from the feed.
   - Call the `/{db}/_changes` API with the seq (stored in redis).
   - Fetch the changed document, call my external API and update the document
2. #### Continuously replicate all databases into a single database.

   - Listen to the `/_changes` feed of this database.
   - Fetch the changed document, call my external API and update the document in the original database (I can easily keep a track of which document originally belongs to which database)

Questions:

1. Does any of the above make sense? Will it scale to 5000 databases?
2. How do I handle failures? It is critical that the API be hit for all documents.

Thanks!

Comment: We actually implemented something similar for our app and are in the process of open sourcing it: https://github.com/redgeoff/spiegel. I think this is a great strategy, but it takes a decent amount of work to handle errors and make it scale.

Comment: Can you please explain how you do these steps from 1. ?? - Call the /{db}/_changes API with the seq (stored in redis). -Fetch the changed document, call my external API and update the document. I am able to listen to changes on `_global_changes` but I can't figure out how to fetch the changed document and its information.

Comment: For this I came across npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow
Using this we build sync mechanism between couch and other databases.